# tunneling mysql into appfog

Tags: php, mysql, tunnel, appfog

I am developing a local website using;
PHP 5.4.6
Apache 2.4.2
MySQL 5.5.27

currently i am implementing a simple login script, with a small database.
on local it works fine.
when i

> af update kirka "%webdev%"
>
> af tunnel

, and then

> source mysql_dump.sql;

everything seems to fly without errors.

then i hook my environmental variables for establishing connection on the webserver using `getenv("VCAP_SERVICES")`

and then my website hosted on appfog starts showing connectivity to the database, but its as if the database is empty, or it fails to select anything from it.
when i redo `source mysql_dump.sql;`, it tells me it had to erase 7 rows, and re-add them. meaning the database is not empty.

why does my appfog instance of the application fail to fetch info from db?
anybody have any experience with this?

pic at localhost; http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/7818/55079155.png

pic at appfog; http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/2983/94724810.png

source code on github; https://github.com/kirka121/CST8285_Webdev

looking forward to a reply folks

Answer (score 0):

i figured out the answer.

I am using

> 

```
 define("TBL_USERS", "users");
 define("TBL_ACTIVE_USERS",  "active_users");
 define("TBL_ACTIVE_GUESTS", "active_guests");
 define("TBL_BANNED_USERS",  "banned_users");
 define("TBL_SETTINGS",  "settings");
```

to select my tables in the database.

where my development (local) is on a windows, my testing (webhost) is on a unix. and unix is case sensitive. my tables in the actual database are starting with capital letters. therefore it did not recognize them on unix, but did on windows. problem fixed.